# How do quantum key distribution systems tolerate noise?

Tags: algorithm-design, protocol-design, quantum-key-distribution, error-propagation

It seems to me that any noise in the signal would result in Alice and Bob generating different keys, without a simple way to tell the difference.

How do quantum key distribution systems tolerate noise?

Comment: Hi Chase. I see you are back with another question. However, this question has an unaccepted answer. Is there anything missing from the answer that blocks you from accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

That question is essentially A.1 of this [lengthy post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51314/555), with some elements of answer in B.1

For your convenience, here’s quoting those specific sections of [his linked answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51311/12164):

> ### A. Issues prevent direct use of sifted bits
>
> …
>
> 1. **Errors creep in the sifted bits**
>
>    The many imperfections of the model (heavily simplified compared to the actual hardware and the known laws of quantum physics, even at the time the [article][2] was written) are such that, without Eve messing, sizably many sifted bits differ at Alice's and Bob's end. Sifted bits are thus unusable as key to a [cipher][3], for decryption would likely fail.
>
> …
>
> ### B. Classical cryptography rooted in information theory fixes them all
>
> 1. **Secret-Key Reconciliation protocol remove errors, and more**
>
>    [Coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory) and [error detection and correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) are used to build a secure [Secret-Key Reconciliation protocol](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=secret%20key%20reconciliation%20protocol) additional to sifting, also running over the classical channels. Its objectives are to
>
>    - remove or fix errors in the sifted bits, with bounded low odds of the contrary;
>    - obtain an upper bound on the actual error rate, which is attributed to Eve spying the quantum channel;
>    - obtain and minimize an upper bound on the information leaked by running the protocol over the classical channels, that Eve is assumed to scrutinize;
>    - deduce a lower bound of what [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) (if any) remains in the rest; if there is less than some headroom, QKD failed.
>
>    Such reconciliation protocol can loose little-enough entropy as to be usable in practice, and be information-theoretically provable; but no simple such one is known. A most scrutinized milestone is the cascade protocol in: Gilles Brassard and Louis Salvail's [*Secret-Key Reconciliation by Public Discussion*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cd81/f9ed8a3adfecf6a69fdf5e1dbf92d7844dcc.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 1993](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_35).
>
> …